# best practices for placing a config file in MVC

Tags: php, model-view-controller

is it best to include the database config file in the controller or should I include the config file in the model? My intuition is telling me that it should be included in the controller. Please verify

Comment: I suggest to create wrapper class for controller and extend it into all controller than load config on wrapper class u will config in any where. Or in mvc u also can include in autoload dont knw which mvc r u using

Comment: @devpro Im not using an actual MVC but im using the same underlining ideas of MVC. But I like your idea of creating a parent class with a config file included in it.

Comment: For yur learning chk codignitor and its autoload process